# How to apply mid-circuit measurement and measurement based conditional operations in `amazon-braket`?

Tags: programming, quantum-gate, quantum-circuit, amazon-braket

Is there any method to apply mid circuit measurements in `amazon-braket`? I'm implementing a circuit that has few operations conditioned to measurement. In `qiskit`, it is possible. I'm wondering how to do it using `braket`?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Braket currently doesn't support mid-circuit measurement; feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-sdk-python/issues) in the Amazon Braket SDK.

It's probably suboptimal, but for the time being, if your conditional operations are Paulis, you can rewrite circuits with [deferred measurement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Measurement_Principle) and the corresponding controlled-Pauli operations. As well, you can run OpenQASM 3 programs with arbitrary controlled operations in the [local simulator](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/braket_features/Simulating_Advanced_OpenQASM_Programs_with_the_Local_Simulator.ipynb) (see cell 5).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate which cell? I couldn't find it.

Comment: Whoops, somehow didn't add the [link](https://github.com/aws/amazon-braket-examples/blob/main/examples/braket_features/Simulating_Advanced_OpenQASM_Programs_with_the_Local_Simulator.ipynb)